# Access to dynamic images on server

Tags: asp.net, image

I'm developing a web application in which users uploads images and I'm keeping the location of the uploaded image path on server. For example:

C:\fix_directory\a8531.jpg

In my page, I want to display this image but I couldn't. I've tried many things but couldn't find a way of doing it.. This directory isn't part of my project because it will be always updated.

What is the effective way of overcoming this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a virtual directory (`yourweb.com/images`) which points to your images, or even a web (`cdn.yourweb.com`).

You could also write a HTTP handler or a file handler (.ashx) in ASP.NET to serve your images from that location.

**Update**

I guess the most effective way *of overcoming this problem* would be to store the uploaded files simply somewhere in your web directory.

**Update 2**

I'm definitley sure, the most effective way *of overcoming this problem* is to have a real IIS or a Visual Studio Development Server and not trying to do anything with the Vista Home Basic pseudo IIS which [can do nothing](http://forums.iis.net/t/1103525.aspx).

Comment: Can this be done without creating a virtual directory? I don't have full IIS so I'm not able to create a virtual directory on localhost so It would be great if I can do it without upgrading my version.

Comment: Question: Why are you not storing the uploaded files simply somewhere in your web directory? And what server version are you using if not IIS? Visual Studio DevServer?

Comment: I'M using IIS but vista home basic version comes with a smaller IIS which doesn't support all features of IIS. I can only run my web apps..

Comment: Well, then the only possible action for you seems to to write any kind of handler (see answers), but I really don't see your point of storing it not within your web directory. Is there any reason it must be stored outside of your web directory?

Comment: how can i store it in  my web directory if I can't create a virtual directory in it? I can't open inetmgr. Any way of doing it?

Comment: Just tell your upload method to not store it at 'C:\fix_directory\' and instead in a folder of your choise which is a subfolder inside of your web directory. For example 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\img\'.

Comment: I have tried that, moved this folder under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ and tried giving path to it like img src="\fix_directory\img.jpg" and it didn't work. I couldn't even reach localhost/myproject/fix_directory/ from adress bar.

Comment: Well, find out in IIS where your web root is looking to and place it there. It will work!

Comment: Mate, I can't open iis manager. (I can't run inetmgr). I can only see the files under wwwroot folder but adding a folder there doesn't bind it to my application. I guess I have to buy a new OS with IIS on it. LOL! thank you MS.

Comment: Can you place a simple 'test.jpg' in the root of your web and access via 'http://localhost/test.jpg'?

Comment: I've tried adding it to both in and out of wwwroot they both give 404. IIS binds the folder/file to the application with virtual directories and without them, it just won't work (I guess.)

Comment: According to here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1103525.aspx Vista home basic only has enough IIS features to support WCF and does not have any of the web-server features (like static-files/directory-listing/asp/asp.net/ssinc etc) ... so you can't do it with your Windows version and also all the other solutions here are obsolet.

Comment: What I would recommend you instead of buying a new Windows, go for Visual Studio Express (which is free) and comes with a development web  server.

Comment: Yes Martin! that is what I'm trying to explain :) but tried my luck with you hehe! Now I need to buy a windows 7 premium and stop coding till I get it up and running :(

Comment: Really? So I get IIS if I install it and will get the features of IIS that I need?

Comment: You don't get the IIS but a 'build-in' Visual Studio development server. But it will do mostly everything for you.

Comment: So I'll be able to create virtual directories at least :) Any guides for using it? Thanks

Comment: You don't need a virtual directory for doing that! Just a folder that it's ;)

Comment: Please open another question or read some documentary/blogs about Visual Studio Express, this one is solved ;)

Comment: I got it up and running but I still can't find a way of doing what I want to do (give path to a local folder and use it within the application)... I can create a folder in my solution / I was also able to create a folder in my solution. How will I map the C:/my_folder/my_image.jpg to my iis folder?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to make `fix_directory` a virtual directory within your project inside of IIS, and access the images that way.

A more complex approach would be to do something in the lines of pulling in your image via a `FileStream`, and outputting it to your website via a `ResponseStream`.

A common way this is achieved is by creating a `generic handler (.ashx)` that's only responsibility is to output your images.

Comment: Can this be done without creating a virtual directory? I don't have full IIS so I'm not able to create a virtual directory on localhost so It would be great if I can do it without upgrading my version.

Comment: George, will the filestream understand the path if I give it like "C:\fix_directory\a8531.jpg" ? this is my only consern..